# Оптимизация ajax

Tags: php, ajax, phpquery, ajax-load

Пишу поиск для сайта, приходится парсить фото с страницы товара,

Так как товаров очень много, нагрузка на сервер большая, подскажите как уменьшить нагрузку или увеличить скорость загрузки.

Использую данный код:

Для вывода товара по соответствию фразе:

```
if(strpos($test, $serching_words) && $product_index <= $product_list && 
$product_index > $product_list0){
                    if($rows2['is_public'] == '1'){
                        $viewed_products++;
                        //
                        echo '<div class="product col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                            <div class="row">

                            <div class="thumb col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                <a href="http://zeta.kz/ru/product/'.$rows2['alias'].'">
                                    <img class="product_photo product_photo_'.$product_index.'" photo-index="'.$product_index.'" photo-url="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/ru/product/'.$rows2['alias'].'" src="/images/preloader.gif">
                                </a>
                                <a href="http://zeta.kz/ru/product/'.$rows2['alias'].'" class="overlay hidden-xs" style="display: none;">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                             <td>
                                                    <i class="icon-zoom75"></i>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="desc col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="http://zeta.kz/ru/product/'.$rows2['alias'].'">
                                        '.$rows2['title'].'
                                 </a>
                                </h3>
                                <p><i>Артикул: '.$rows2['vendor_code'].'</i></p>
                                <p class="price product_price_'.$product_index.'">
                                    &nbsp; <span class="small_italic">KZT</span>
                                </p>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="'.$rows2['product_id'].'" data-action="5" class="cart_action add_to_cart btn btn_green_tr">Купить</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        </div>';
                        //
                    }
                }
```

Сам ajax-запрос для парсинга фото:

```
echo "
            <script>
                $( '.product_photo' ).each(function() {
                    var product_index = $(this).attr('photo-index');
                    var url = $(this).attr('photo-url');
                    //
                    $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: '/prokladka/search/index.php',
                      data: 'class='+product_index+'&url='+url,
                      success: function(data){
                        $('.results').append(data);
                      }
                    });
                    //
                });
            </script>
";
```

Сам файл обработчик запроса:

```
// incoming vars
$url = $_POST['url'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
// incoming vars
//
// including lib
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/prokladka/lib/phpquery-master/phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
// including lib
//
// lets start parsing
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($page);
//
$img = $document->find('.product-album img')->attr('src');
$price = $document->find('.product-single .price')->html();
$price = trim(preg_replace('~\s+~s', ' ', $price)); 
//
echo "
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.product_photo_$class').attr('src','$img');
            $('.product_price_$class').html('".$price."');
        });
    </script>
";
// lets start parsing
```

Comment: А фото отдельно в БД нет чтоль?

Comment: Вот в этом вся соль, что нету, незнаю что делать, поиск сначала в бд находит соответствующий товар, а их периодически 400+, а потом парсит AJAX-ом фото, это только что  бы один запрос в поиск выполнить, а там каждую минуту люди ищут, поэтому тупа сайт начинает глючить, я думаю что по большей степени это из за AJAX-запросов, так как без фото он не напрягаясь и быстро справляется

Comment: @Maksat Sh если товар в бд, значит это динамическая страница. если это динамическая страница, как тогда изображение товара сопоставляется с товаром если не из бд??? У вас доступ к базе данных есть?

Comment: Да имеется, но там нету такого селектора как url-картинки, может фото при отправке на сервер шифрует название его, но зачем это, как я понял на сервере используется EFineUploader